# javascript-need help in generate list and call function on any list items

Tags: javascript

Can I generate an unordered or ordered list in `JavaScript` without using any input?

If yes, then how?

I just code a function which generates a list but with the help of an input field, while I want it without any input field.

Also if I want call another function from any list items, how can I do this?

```js
var database = [];

function submit(i) {
  var name = document.getElementById("enter");
  var theName = name.value;
  database.push(theName);
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "";
  for (var I = 0; I < database.length; I++) {


    hotlelist = "<li>" + database[I] + "</li>";
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML += hotlelist;
  }

}
```

```html
<input id="enter" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Enter name" onclick="submit(id)">
<div id="name">
</div>
```

Comment: Did you call it in your code? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: actually i want to generate a list of hotels and then i want when i clcike on any list items it gives me a room of clicked hotel..can u tell me how it will works ???

Comment: You can fill your array: `var database = ["Hotle1","Hotle2","Hotle3"]; function genHot() { for (var i = 0; i < database.length; i++) { .... }}` and change your div to ul - lastly: `hotlelist = "<li onclick='showHotle('+i+')'">" + database[i] + "</li>";`

Comment: @mplungjan While you are correct that you shouldn't name anything `submit`, it is not a reserved word.  I think "browser method name" would be a better phrase.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Right. For all intents and purposes it SHOULD have been reserved and should be treated as one. _**Never** use the word `submit` for any variables, field names or methods. It is best to avoid using it at all except when invoking a form's submit method_

Comment: thanks @mplungjan its very helping for me but i still stuck at point

Comment: @mplungjan sir i have generate list of hotels sucessfully just like                         
.Hotel 1
.hotel2
hotel3
now i want when i clicked on hotel 1 or any hotel the any function should me call and it should show me its respective rooms to me..

Answer (score 0):

try this demo or just move your mouse over the item,you will see:
https://jsfiddle.net/xianshenglu/9f823d7j/

```js
    var database = [{name:'items1',data:' hotel1 or other information'},{name:'items2',data:' hotel2 or other information'}];
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fragment.innerHTML = '';

    database.forEach(function(item) {
        let li=document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML=item.name;
        li.setAttribute('data-detail', item.data);
        fragment.appendChild(li);
    })
    let name=document.getElementById("name");
    name.appendChild(fragment);

    name.addEventListener('mouseover',function () {
        //console.log(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase());
        if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==='li') {
            let details=document.createElement('span');
            details.className='details';
            details.innerHTML=event.target.getAttribute('data-detail');
            event.target.appendChild(details);
        }
    } ,false);
    name.addEventListener('mouseout',function () {
        if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase()==='li') {
            let details=document.getElementsByClassName('details')[0];
                event.target.removeChild(details);
        }
    } ,false);
```

```html
<div class="po">
  item
 <ul id="name"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: suppose if i clicked on item1 ..after clicked it display me related things of item 1??for example suppose items1 (hotel1) if i clicked on hotel 1 it shows my its related details like room or another list of room ???

Comment: how can i do tthis ?

Comment: i guess you are using Firefox,,,,try it with chrome

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create html elements with js, example:

```
var unOrderedList = document.createElement('ul');
var listItem = document.createElement('li');
var contentText = document.createTextNode("item 1!");
listItem.appendChild(contentText);
unOrderedList.appendChild(listItem);
document.body.appendChild(unOrderedList); // or any other element were you want to insert list
```